# How to prevent removing preexising GAC entries during uninstall of msi via Wix

Tags: wix, windows-installer, gac

I have a wix script which places some shared Dll s which are commonly used by different applications. If the dll is already registered by another msi, no problem it won't be deleted unless all msi using it uninstalled. But in my case the entries are manually registered to the GAC so they do not tied up to any msi. They are removed during uninstall and I don't want that. How can you tell an msi package to keep any preexisting gac entries after uninstall?

Answer (score 0):

Basically according to [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/905238/en-us) if you schedule `RemoveExistingProducts` too early, the GAC items will be removed. Maybe try `RemoveExistingProducts` later in the sequence and see if that helps. Haven't tried this just seen your question and was reading that article. :)